# Save Text to Columns as Values

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with identification codes that are eight characters in length (all numerical). Every two digits represents a unique identifier. For example, code `10203040` is Vehicles (10), Trucks (20), 4x4 (30), Toyota (40). In an Excel sheet, I want people to be able to enter an 8-digit code and have it display the Level 1, 2, 3 and 4 descriptors as well as the full description. How I am achieving that now is by taking the 8-digit code, converting it to text to columns via fixed width, and then doing a VLOOKUP on each 2-digit code. The macro for this is:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim UNSPSC As String
    UNSPSC = Range("A2")

    Range("B2") = UNSPSC

    Range("B2").Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

While this works, the problem is that anyone who does multiple searches has to click an annoying warning about replacing the cells in each time (the text to columns are hidden). Is there a way to store the text to column products as a value or string so that this warning isn't displayed (i.e. there is no overwriting of data in cells)? I could, theoretically, then pull the values into the VLOOKUP inside the macro/VBA code.

Comment: Have you considered simply suppressing the alert messages?  At the beginning of the code you could add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but remember to turn it back on at the end with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.  Read more about [DisplayAlerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: ^good suggestions.  I was thinking of generating a new, empty sheet, and populating that with your values.  No need to worry about overwrites.

Comment: Thank you, Josh. I wasn't familiar with those commands. Used those and it works like a dream. I figured there had to be some simpler solution. Thank you!

Comment: If your Vehicles could be less than 10 (only one digit) then you might want to use 00000000 as a number format in A2 and use `UNSPSC = Format(Range("A2"), "00000000")`

Answer (score 0):

OP seems may prefer turning off alerts but for the sake of answer, add:

```
Range("B2:E2") = ""
```

immediately after the Dim statement.